# Unable to fill the edit texbox of a aspxgridview inside another aspxgridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a ASPxGridView with a popup edit form which contains another ASPxGridView. When i open the edit form i can see the ASPxGridView i can click on add and then there appears a texbox to fill with a name. When i click on that textbox nothing happens in Opera 11 and i cannot enter anything in the textbox. When i tried to do the same on FireFox 4 i did get a cursor but i was not able to input any text either. Then i tried Chrome 10.0.648.204 but that did the same as Opera and somehow IE 9 gives me a HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request which is kinda weird as it is the only browser with that error.
This is made up out of 2 DevExpress gridviews.

I am not sure what code is causing this but here is the "sub"gridview :

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Visible="False" VisibleIndex="14" 
        Caption="Parameter(s)" FieldName="ASPxGV3">
        <EditFormSettings Visible="True" />
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                        <EditButton Visible="True">
                        </EditButton>
                        <NewButton Visible="True">
                        </NewButton>
                        <DeleteButton Visible="True">
                        </DeleteButton>
                    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Naam" Name="Naam" VisibleIndex="0">
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                </Columns>
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the FieldName property of the column to make it editable.

Comment: Well i added Naam as KeyFieldName but that did not work. Would it have something to do with wrong databinding then?

Comment: I do not see that the column's FieldName is set.  Set this property to allow the end-user edit its data.  Also, the GridView's KeyFieldName property should be set.

Comment: I mean that i tried it out but added keyfieldname instead of fieldname now i also added the columns fieldname and it's working like a charm now. Thanks allot.

Comment: I would like to add that it still does not appear to work in IE 9. i don't know if it should aside i don't need it to work on IE 9 but i thought i would just add this just in case